# Is there a way for .php URL to invoke NEXTJS web app - preferably on AWS Amplify?

Tags: php, aws-amplify, next.js13

I have currently a WORDPRESS site which handles the following type of URL:

"https://example.com/login.php?XXX=xxx&Lan=en&App=yyyOnelogin&API=13.0&Token=z4z5z6z7z8&OneLogin=zzz"

I am switching it to be a NEXTJS based web app. Is it possible to achieve this on AWS Amplify ?

I have succeefully tested the way to invoke the nextjs app, via a login.php url,  on localhost using xampp:

```
    $nextjs_app_url = "http://localhost:3000/" ;
    if (!headers_sent()) {
        header("Location: " . $nextjs_app_url);
        exit;
    }
```